# What is the correct way to grant permissions using SAML tokens in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, claims-based-auth, adfs

Hi We have a sharepoint 2013 instance and we are setting up claims based authentication with SAML assertions (ADFS 3.0 IDP). I am able to grant access to a user by adding the user's email address to the web application's user policy. This works fine however I am unable to grant access by group.

I created claim type mappings for email,UPN,Role, and SID.

```
$emailClaimMap = New-SPClaimTypeMapping -IncomingClaimType   "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress" -IncomingClaimTypeDisplayName "EmailAddress" -SameAsIncoming
$upnClaimMap = New-SPClaimTypeMapping -IncomingClaimType "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn" -IncomingClaimTypeDisplayName "UPN" -SameAsIncoming
$roleClaimMap = New-SPClaimTypeMapping -IncomingClaimType "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" -IncomingClaimTypeDisplayName "Role" -SameAsIncoming
$sidClaimMap = New-SPClaimTypeMapping -IncomingClaimType "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/primarysid" -IncomingClaimTypeDisplayName "SID" -SameAsIncoming
```

Here are the ADFS claim rules

[image: ADFS Claim Rules]

What is the correct way to grant access to a user based on group membership?

Comment: what error you are getting when type the group? are you typing group name or what?

Comment: No error, I just get permission denied when I try to access the site as a user that is a member of the test group. I am typing in the Netbios name of the group (picker doesn't work since it's using an IDP).

Comment: check this one http://www.sharepointsecurity.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-security/adfs-not-resolving-active-directory-security-groups-in-sharepoint/

Comment: It looks like our settings match those in the link you referenced and I don't think the hotfix is applicable since we are on Sharepoint 2013.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The group I was using was configured as a Distribution group and not a Security group.

Also, when using the picker for adding a user/group to a sharepoint group I had to mouse over the search result and make sure I selected the entry with the Role claim.